# how to send javascript values in html table

Tags: javascript, html

I got the values throw sDocStr. and now i need to send sDocStr values to that html table.. can anyone help me.

```
function myFunction()
        {
        document.write(sDocStr);
        mytable += "<html><table>";
        mytable += "<tr><td style='font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;'>sDocStr</td></tr>";
        mytable += "</table></html>";
        }
```

Comment: This code seems to be copy-pasted together and doesn't make much sense on its own. If you are a beginner and want to learn javascript, i recommend reading this: http://eloquentjavascript.net/

Answer (score -1):

Try following:

```
function myFunction()
        {
        //considering cDocStr has some value
        var mytable='';
        mytable += "<table>";
        mytable += "<tr><td style='font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;'>"+sDocStr+"</td></tr>";
        mytable += "</table>";
        document.write(mytable);
        }
```

Comment: Oops! can any one plz explain why the answers are VOTE DOWN?

Answer (score -1):

you can do this :

```
function myFunction() {
    document.write(sDocStr);
    mytable += "<html><table>";
    mytable += "<tr><td style='font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;'>" + sDocStr + "</td></tr>";
    mytable += "</table></html>";
}
```

is that ok for you ?

Comment: yes. thank you.. and i need to print those values in table format but it displayed as a para..

Comment: hum... What does that mean ?

Comment: @user3732856 just concat the formatted markup with the returned data. its not too hard

Comment: ok add this : document.write(mytable); in the end of myfunction().

Comment: hey @4x3LDev, do u have any idea why the answers are being donwvoted? and user of this post got the result using your solution too...(modifying to some extent) then what downvoter have a problem with..and looking towards the score of user i guess he is newbee so we dont point out the errors in his post :(